# Adding the sum of two values in a query

Tags: php, mysql

SO i made a query which gets the following result

```
 +---------------+---------------+---------+---------
 | payID         | payRate       | hours   | Earnings
 +---------------+---------------+---------+--------
 |  entertainment| 12            |      18 | 216
 |        retail | 10            |      28 | 280
 +---------------+---------------+---------+----------
```

The query and some other part of code is as follows:

```
 $query = "SELECT jobId, payRate, SUM(hours) AS 'All_Hours' ,payRate * SUM(hours) AS 'total'
                       FROM users INNER JOIN deposit ON userId = empId
                      WHERE users.email = '" . $_SESSION['email'] ."' 
                      GROUP BY jobId,payRate";



                      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query); //we make the query

                  if (!$result) { //if the query failed
                   echo("<p id = 'greatideadescription'>
                              Error, the query could not be executed: " .
                   mysqli_error($db) . "</p>");
                   mysqli_close($db);}

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { //if no rows returned
                   echo("<tr><td />
                               <td>No Results</td>
                               <td /></tr>");
                   mysqli_close($db); //close the database
                   exit("</table></div></form></div></div>
                               <script>DisplayFooter();</script></body></html>");
                        } 
                       $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result); //gets number of rows
                       $numFields = mysqli_num_fields($result); //gets number of fields
                       //prints the data in the table
                       PrintTable($result, $numRows, $numFields);
```

the function PrintTable is as follows

```
 function PrintTable($result, $numRows, $numFields) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); //fetches the first row
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
  echo("<tr>"); //opens a new row

  for ($j = 0; $j < $numFields; $j++) { //second loop goes through columns
  echo("<td>" . $row[$j] . "</td>"); 
   } //end inner for loop

   $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); //fetches subsequent rows
   echo("</tr>"); //closes the row
   } //end outer for loop
  }
```

what i want is to echo the sum of the earnings which in this case it will be 496
How can I do that?

Comment: You could use the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier to the `GROUP BY` clause of your SQL: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-modifiers.html.

Comment: the rollup didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you know the column index your sum column you can try something like this:

```
function PrintTable($result, $numRows, $numFields) {
    $total = 0; // Initialize variable before going through each row
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); //fetches the first row
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numRows; $i++) {
        echo("<tr>"); //opens a new row

        for ($j = 0; $j < $numFields; $j++) { //second loop goes through columns
            echo("<td>" . $row[$j] . "</td>");
            if($j == 3)
              $total += $row[$j];
        } //end inner for loop

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); //fetches subsequent rows
        echo("</tr>"); //closes the row
    } //end outer for loop
}
```

After that you can use your total or return it into your main code to echo it after closing the table or or or...

The better way would be to make 3 changes:

1. `payRate * SUM(hours) AS earnings` in your sql statement, you will use that name later
2. use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get an associative array where you can access columns by name (`$row['earnings']`)
3. use a foreach-loop for the columns as you do not have an index you can iterate over

It's up to you which way you use...